# Resizing VBA Vlookup to include next lookup value

Tags: vba, excel

The problem with this code is that, when the formula is resized to encapsulate all the values in the row, the lookup value reference stays the same.  That is, if the first cell has a lookup value of 50.88, the next cell below it keeps that same lookup value of 50.88, but I want it to advance to the next number on the list instead.

Does anyone know how to incorporate something that adds +1 to rownum when it moves on to the next value?

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
Dim rownum As Long
Dim colnum As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim colindexval As Double
Dim resizeval As Double
Dim fVLOOKUP As String


rownum = Sheet1.Cells(28, 21).Value
colnum = Sheet1.Cells(27, 21).Value
x = Sheet1.Cells(20, 21).Value
y = Sheet1.Cells(21, 21).Value
resizeval = Sheet1.Cells(19, 12).Value
colindexval = Sheet1.Cells(29, 12).Value

fVLOOKUP = "=VLOOKUP(@1,'@2'!@3,@4,FALSE)"

fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@1", Sheet9.Cells(rownum, colnum).Value)
fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@2", Sheets("Price Data").Name)
fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@3", Sheets("Price        Data").Range("A12").CurrentRegion.Address)
fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@4", colindexval)

Sheet9.Cells(y, x).Resize(resizeval, 1).Formula = fVLOOKUP


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as follows.  Using a fill down technique, excel should be able to do the rest of the work for you.

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
Dim rownum As Long
Dim colnum As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim colindexval As Double
Dim resizeval As Double
Dim fVLOOKUP As String


rownum = Sheet1.Cells(28, 21).Value
colnum = Sheet1.Cells(27, 21).Value
x = Sheet1.Cells(20, 21).Value
y = Sheet1.Cells(21, 21).Value
resizeval = Sheet1.Cells(19, 12).Value
colindexval = Sheet1.Cells(29, 12).Value

fVLOOKUP = "=VLOOKUP(@1,'@2'!@3,@4,FALSE)"

fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@1", Sheet9.Cells(rownum, colnum).Address(false, false))
fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@2", Sheets("Price Data").Name)
fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@3", Sheets("Price        Data").Range("A12").CurrentRegion.Address)
fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@4", colindexval)

Sheet9.Cells(y, x).Value = fVLOOKUP
Sheet9.Range(Cells(y, x), Cells.Offset(resizeval, 1)).FillDown


End Sub
```

Note, when using .Address in excel VBA, the default is to include the $ to lock the cell address down, by doing .Address(False, False) it removes them.

Answer (score 0):

this might give you something to think about

```
Dim i as integer 
for each acell in  Sheet9.Cells(y, x).Resize(resizeval, 1)

    fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@1", Sheet9.Cells(rownum+1, colnum).address)
    fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@2", Sheets("Price Data").Name)
    fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@3", Sheets("Price        Data").Range("A12").CurrentRegion.Address)
    fVLOOKUP = Replace(fVLOOKUP, "@4", colindexval)


    acell.Formula = fVLOOKUP
    i = i + 1

next acell
```